# Authorization policy via attribute before data binding in web api

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I am struggling to find a good solution for doing custom authorization checks without having to repeat the authorization check manually over and over again.

To illustrate, suppose I have the following setup for a .net core web api, which has two endpoints, one for GET and one for POST. I would like to check (maybe against db) whether the user has the right to see the resource, or the right to create a resource.

This is what the documentation refers to as [resource based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
and would look something like this:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiVersion ("1.0")]
[Route ("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ResourcesController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

    //..constructor DI

    [HttpGet ("{resourceId}")]
    public ActionResult<Resource> Get (Guid resourceId) {
        var authorizationCheck = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync (User, resourceId, ServiceOperations.Read);
        if (!authorizationCheck.Succeeded) {
            return Forbid ();
        }

        return Ok (ResourceRep.Get (resourceId));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Resource> Post ([FromBody] Resource resource) {
        var authorizationCheck = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync (User, null, ServiceOperations.Write);
        if (!authorizationCheck.Succeeded) {
            return Forbid ();
        }

        return Ok (ResourceRep.Create (resource));
    }
}
```

Now imagine the `ServiceOperations` enum has a long list of supported operations, or there are 100 different endpoints, I will have to do the same check everywhere, or even worse, might forget to add a check where I should definitely have added a check. And there is not an easy way to pick this up in unit tests.

I thought of using attributes but as the docs state:

> Attribute evaluation occurs before data binding and before execution of the page handler or action that loads the document. For these reasons, declarative authorization with an [Authorize] attribute doesn't suffice. Instead, you can invoke a custom authorization method—a style known as imperative authorization.

So it seems I cannot use an authorization policy and decorate the methods with authorization attributes (which are easy to unit test that they are there) when the check itself requires a parameter that is not available (the resourceId).

So for the **question** itself:
How do you use imperative (resource based) authorization generically without having to repeat yourself (which is error-prone). I would love to have an attribute like the following:

```
[HttpGet ("{resourceId}")]
[AuthorizeOperation(Operation = ServiceOperations.Read, Resource=resourceId)]
public ActionResult<Resource> Get (Guid resourceId) {..}

[AuthorizeOperation(Operation = ServiceOperations.Write)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Resource> Post ([FromBody] Resource resource) {..}
```

Comment: What is the actual purpose of your AuthorizeOperation attribute? [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] are interchangable on Controllers and Actions so you fine tune your requirements that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `AuthorizationHandler` in a policy-based authorization and combine with an injected service specifically created to determine the Operation-Resources pairing.

To do it, first setup the policy in `Startup.ConfigureServices` :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("OperationResource", policy => policy.Requirements.Add( new OperationResourceRequirement() ));
});
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, UserResourceHandler>();
services.AddScoped<IOperationResourceService, OperationResourceService>();
```

next create the `OperationResourceHandler` :

```
public class OperationResourceHandler: AuthorizationHandler<OperationResourceRequirement>
{
    readonly IOperationResourceService _operationResourceService;

    public OperationResourceHandler(IOperationResourceService o)
    {
        _operationResourceService = o;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authHandlerContext, OperationResourceRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
        {
            var area = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["area"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var controller = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var action = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var id = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"] as string)?.ToLower();
            if (_operationResourceService.IsAuthorize(area, controller, action, id))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }               
        }            
    }
}
```

the `OperationResourceRequirement` can be an empty class:

```
public class OperationResourceRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

The trick is, rather than specify action's Operation in attribute, we specify it elsewhere such as in database, in appsettings.json, in some config file, or hardcoded.

Here's an example getting the Operation-Resource pair from config file:

```
public class OperationResourceService : IOperationResourceService
{
    readonly IConfiguration _config;
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

    public class OpeartionResourceService(IConfiguration c, IHttpContextAccessor a, UserManager<AppUser> u) 
    {
        _config = c;
        _accessor = a;
        _userManager = u;
    }

    public bool IsAuthorize(string area, string controller, string action, string id)
    {
        var operationConfig = _config.GetValue<string>($"OperationSetting:{area}:{controller}:{action}"); //assuming we have the setting in appsettings.json
        var appUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_accessor.HttpContext.User);
        //all of needed data are available now, do the logic of authorization
        return result;
    } 
}
```

Please note that to make `IHttpContextAccessor` injectable, add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` in `Startup.ConfigurationServices` method body.

After all is done, use the policy on an action:

```
[HttpGet ("{resourceId}")]
[Authorize(Policy = "OperationResource")]
public ActionResult<Resource> Get (Guid resourceId) {..}
```

the authorize policy can be the same for every action.